# Visual C++ 2012: compiler complains about "missing ';'"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Could you please point out to me what is wrong with the following template class?

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename C>
struct pQueue{
    pQueue():currEnd(c.end()){};
    ~pQueue(){c.~vector();}
    void insert(T& t);
    void remove(T& t);
    bool find(T& t);
    T head(void);
private:
    std::vector<T> c;
    std::vector<T>::iterator currEnd;
};
```

The compiler isn't very happy about the `std::vector<T>::iterator currEnd;` line, and produces the following error messages:

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'currEnd'

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Thank you very much!

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords). By the way, GCC and Clang give extremely straightforward errors for this.

Comment: Luckily, gcc suggests the solution: http://ideone.com/tUQz2B

Comment: Not related to the errors, but you are explicitly invoking a destructor from `~pQueue()`. Why? Since `c` is an actual vector and not a pointer, its destructor would run anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the compiler doesn't recognise `std::vector<T>::iterator` as a type. You have to tell it:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator currEnd;
```

`typename` is used as disambiguitator in templated context. It just tells the compiler that the identifier `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a type rather than a static member. The standard requires this in the templated context, even though in most cases the compiler could work that out even before the template parameter `T` has been specified.

---

While the above answers your question, I can only emphasize what juanchopanza has pointed out about your code. Besides, there is `std::queue` for you already.

Comment: It compiles indeed. But what exactly does "typename" keyword do in this context?

Comment: @user2531913 It tells the compiler that vector<T>::iterator is a type, and not a static member variable.

Comment: It's a priority queue though. I can use the priority_queue, but I can't seem to figure out how to take things off it; I can also use std::set, but I guess I'd rather implement a proper one myself which does exactly what a priority queue is supposed to do.

Comment: @user2531913 `std::priority_queue` has members `top()` to access the top element and `pop()` to remove it. `push()` and `emplace()` insert a new element (and sort the queue in log(N) time). You cannot remove others than the top element.

Comment: @Walter It's A* search, wouldn't I need to sometimes re-evaluate the same node and, if it turns out to have a shorter distance to the starting node than before, take it off the queue and insert it again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler the iterator is a type name, because it is a dependent name:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator currEnd;
```

Besides that, this class does not need a user-provided destructor. Your class definition could be simplified to this:

```
template <typename T>
struct pQueue
{
    pQueue() : currEnd(c.end()) {};
    void insert(const T& t);
    void remove(const T& t);
    bool find(const T& t);   // this should probably be a const method
    T head();                // this should probably be a const method
private:
    std::vector<T> c;
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator currEnd;
};
```

Comment: I want to use std::remove, so that I can take things out of the priority queue without actually freeing them while keeping track of where the end of queue actually is. Thanks for pointing out the consts, I have added them in.

Comment: @user2531913 Oh I see, so you keep an `end` iterator that isn't necessarily the end of `c`? I think I might have done something similar with a queue once...

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be  `typename std::vector<T>::iterator currEnd;`.

Then the <s>compilcater</s> <s>compilator</s> compiler can figure out that `iterator` is actually a type and not a member (of `std::vector`).

Comment: The visual studio compiler is indeed a 'complicater' :)

Answer (score 0):

Just by way of addendum to the other answers:

Sadly, VisualStudio doesn't have very good error messages. You pretty much have to learn what they mean, rather than read them literally. For example:

`missing ';' before identifier 'currEnd'`

Is VisualStudio-ese typically means "I don't know what the identifier before `currEnd` is." Usually this is due to it being  undefined at that point. 9 times out of 10, it will be a type/class name for a type/class that you neglected to `#include` the header for. In this case it looks like it was more a matter of the compiler getting confused with a template use in a template.

However, the principle stands. Had you started with, "The compiler doesn't know what the type/class before `currEnd` is.", you would have been on the right track.